# What do these signals mean: activated, entered, pressed, viewportEntered?

Tags: python, pyside2

I see these signals in **PySide2.QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView**, some of which are easy to understand, such as **clicked**, **doubleClicked**. For some, the meaning cannot be determined, such as **activated**, **entered**, **pressed**, **viewportEntered**. These signals are also not explained in the manual:https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QAbstractItemView.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.activated

In fact, I want to emit a signal when **QTreeView.currentIndex** changes. I used **clicked** before, but when I use the keyboard up and down arrows to select items, **clicked** doesn't work.

Comment: You might find the [C++ documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#signals) a bit more informative.

Comment: To obtain current changed signal connect to `currentChanged` signal of `QTreeView::selectionModel()` after setting model

Comment: Clicked means mouse clicked, of course its not emited on keyboard events

Comment: @mugiseyebrows PySide2.QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.currentChanged(current, previous) is "slot", not "signal". I can't QTreeView.currentChanged.connect(My_Receiver)

Comment: @mugiseyebrows maybe you're confusing with the item *selection model*, which has the [currentChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentChanged) signal.

Comment: @g2m.agent you could subclass the view and override `currentChanged` in order to *also* send the signal.

Comment: On the other hand, you can just connect to the currentChanged signal of the `selectionModel()`

Comment: @musicamante i'm not confusing, I wrote about selection's model `currentChanged` signal, the same thing you wrote (twice)

Comment: @mugiseyebrows sorry, that comment was meant for g2m.agent.